# Win XP fax program

Tags: windows-xp, fax

I finally got to use this pesty program and got to send my first fax...but confused on how it all plays out.

First, I only sent 1 page + cover and all I get in the Fax monitor showing that it sent just the one page...nothing said about the cover..so I do not know if its automatically sent with the one page. Also, thinking that I was through sending fax, a few minutes later the monitor appears again sending that same page again... does anyone know why?

BTW, I am using this on my home landline phone...so I would have to disconnect the phone line from the pc or junction box in order for me to answer my phone when it rings. Hate the idea that I have to unplug/plug the phone line...is there a better way?

Finally, i suspect that the reason the program started to send another of the same fax, somewhere I had recall that I entered how many times to send a fax in the event the line is busy, but forgot where i did that. Maybe that is where i can stop it for repeating?

Comment: You don't need to swap cords to use the phone. Plug the phone into the pass-through port on the modem. That is what they are designed for. I would suggest reading - [How to enable and configure the fax service in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306550)

Comment: How are we suppose to help you with this problem you face if you don't even tell us **WHAT PROGRAM YOU ARE USING**? Furthermore the solution to the phoneline problem is not use the phoneline.  One might be able to assume your talking about the built-in program, but there are also hundreds of similar products, so best be specific.